# Labeling the axis with alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

consider the code index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>D3 test</title>
          <style>

       .grid .tick {
stroke: lightgrey;
        opacity: 0.7;
   }
      .grid path {
stroke-width: 0;
 }
  .chart {
     }
    .main text {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
 }
    .axis line, .axis path {
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
stroke: black;
fill: none;
    }
    circle {
fill: steelblue;
      }



     </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js">   

                    </script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='content'>
      <!-- /the chart goes here -->
    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="scatterchart.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and scatterchart.js whose script is as follows

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#b41f2d", "#ff7f0e"]);

     var data = [

[2,2],
[3,3],

[4,4],
[5, 4],
[5.5, 5],
[6, 6],
[6, 7],

[6.5,8],
[6.5,16],

[17, 16]
 ];

var margin = {
top: 20,
right: 15,
bottom: 60,
left: 25
   }, width = 950 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 480 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
return d[0];
   })])
 .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
return d[1];
 })])
//.range([height, 0]) //flip y
.range([0, height]);

      var chart = d3.select('body')
.append('svg:svg')
.attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.attr('class', 'chart');

    var main = chart.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.attr('class', 'main');

   // draw the x axis
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
  //.orient('bottom')
.orient('top'); // adjust ticks to new x axis position

    main.append('g')
//.attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)') // move x axis up
.attr('class', 'main axis date')
.call(xAxis);

     // draw the y axis
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient('left');

 main.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
.attr('class', 'main axis date')
.call(yAxis);

  var g = main.append("svg:g");

  g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("svg:circle")
.attr("cx", function (d, i) {
return x(d[0]);
 }) 
 .attr("cy", function (d) {
return y(d[1]);
 }) 
.attr("r", 5)
.style("fill", function (d) { return color(d[0]);}) ;

     // begin of drawing lines
 var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d){return x(d[0]);})
.y(function(d){return y(d[1]);})
.interpolate("linear");  

 g.append("path")
.attr("d", function(d) { return line(data)})
.attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
.style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("fill", "none");
  // end of drawing lines

   main.append("g")
.attr("class", "grid")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(make_x_axis()
.tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
.tickFormat(""))

      main.append("g")
.attr("class", "grid")
.call(make_y_axis()
.tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
.tickFormat(""))

  function make_x_axis() {
return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(30)
  }

   function make_y_axis() {
return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(17)
  }
```

In this example how to label the x-axis as x1,x2,x3..... so on instead of 0,1,2,...and y-axis as y1,y2,y3.... so on instead of 0,1,2,?

Comment: Use the [`.tickFormat()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [axis.tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat) to define a simple custom formatter.  Here's an example for the x axis:

```
axis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return "x" + d;
});
```

Comment: var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, axis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return "x" + d;

})]) Is this correct way of adding .tickformat ?

Comment: No, it doesn't have anything to do with setting up the scale.  That should be done the same as before.  Then, when you create the axis (make_x_axis in your example) you should call tickFormat on the axis.  When the axis is rendered it will call into your formatter for each tick label it is going to render.

Comment: function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .axis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return "x" + d;
})
} Is it here that I should put .tickformat ?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.  You'll need do also do it for the y axis, of course.  Does it work?

Comment: What do your tick labels look like when it doesn't work?  If you put a break point in the code, is the value of d what you'd expect?

Comment: It has the same number format as before, with gridlines disappearing

Comment: How to change the label X,Y to A,B ? i.e. X1,X2,X3 to A1,A2,A3 ?

Comment: At this point it's probably best if you can get the code running in a jsfiddle or somewhere.  It sounds like there are issues beyond tick label formatting.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f337J/ changing label from X0,X1..... to A0,A1.... and Y0,Y1.... to B0,B1.... ?

Comment: Oh, you just want to change the x to an A and the y to a B? You just change the string constant in your tickFormat functions. http://jsfiddle.net/f337J/2/