# How to make the gridlines in the chart static

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

consider the example in the link [Labeling the axis with alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511072/labeling-the-axis-with-alphanumeric-characters). In this example the gridlines are dynamic that is the number of gridlines increases or decreases according to co-ordinate values. How to make this static i.e. make the chart as it is in the example independent of co-ordinate values ?

NOTE :- By changing the last co-ordinate value [17,16] the entire chart is either compressed or expanded depending on co-ordinate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to fix the upper range of the domain. As a simple example, if you know your values in x and y will not exceed 30, you can do this:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,30])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,30])
    .range([0, height]);
```

Comment: Thanks FernOfTheAndes, you have helped me so much, high regards to you. Also can you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511072/labeling-the-axis-with-alphanumeric-characters ?

Comment: @user3438326 Is this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f337J/) what you need for the axis label formatting?

Comment: Wow !!! This is exactly what I was looking for. But can I give the data values i.e. var data = [ [x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x2,y3]....]  so on ?

Comment: @user3438326 If I understand you correctly, I posted a response (with fiddle included) for you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531525/creating-more-than-one-array-for-dataset#22531999).

Comment: Thank you FernOfTheAndes, this is what I was looking for. I asked an extended question i.e. can I use co-ordinate values itself instead of numeric values in var data ?

Comment: YMW. What would the format be for these coordinates?

Comment: Co-ordinate format - In degrees, with N,S suffixed to X and E,W suffixed to Y. And one more question how to load var data from a json or csv or tsv file ? once again Thank you so much FernOfTheAndes.