# Creating more than one array for dataset

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Consider the example shown in the link [Labeling the axis with alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511072/labeling-the-axis-with-alphanumeric-characters). How to create multiple arrays for the var data ? i.e. two separate for the lines [2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5, 4],[5.5, 5] and [6, 6],[6, 7],[6.5,8],[6.5,16],[17, 16] ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: It would make the question clearer, more complete and easier to answer if you could move relevant parts of the example here and explicitly say what is the expected behavior (using pictures, if possible).

Comment: Do you just mean var data = { x: array1, y: array2 } and then you can just user data.x = [ [2,3], [3,3] ] and data.y = [ [4,3] , [5,3] ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, I think at this point, you want to start factoring out your code. So, building on this [EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524685/how-to-make-the-gridlines-in-the-chart-static) I have built for you before (inside my comment), here is an [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f337J/1/) with both lines. You can factor out the code some more, but this should get you going.

```
// begin of drawing dots
drawDots(data);
drawDots(data2);
// end of drawing dots
```