# data parsing using a csv file in d3

Tags: javascript, html, csv, svg, d3.js

consider the example shown in the link [Labeling the axis with alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511072/labeling-the-axis-with-alphanumeric-characters). Is this the correct way to parse var data?

```
var data = []
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    data = data.forEach(function(d) { return [ x[d[0]], y[d[1]]] });
    console.log(data)
});
```

data.csv should hold these values

```
[2, 2],
[3, 3],
[4, 4],
[5, 4],
[5.5, 5],
[6, 6],
[6, 7],
[6.5, 8],
[6.5, 16],
[17, 16]
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "parse", but no, the code you've posted won't work.

Comment: I want data values to come from external csv file i.e load data from a csv file in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you meant that `data` should hold those values, your `data.csv` should look like the following:

```
first,second
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,4
5.5,5
6,6
6,7
6.5,8
6.5,16
17,16
```

And then you can parse it using the names of the fields:

```
var data = []
d3.csv("data.csv", function(csvData) {
    // By default, all the values read are treated as strings.
    // So have to make them numbers explicitly
    data = csvData.forEach(function(d) { return [ +d.first, +d.second ] });
    console.log(data);

    // Draw the chart here.
});
```

Comment: I'm not getting the output, I'm getting a blank chart without any datapoints on it.

Comment: @user3438326 Is the date being read correctly (check by looking at the `console.log`)? And if so, then are you drawing the chart _outside_ the callback? The call to fetch the `csv` file is made asynchronously and any code outside `d3.csv`'s callback will be executed before data has been fetched.

Comment: *TypeError: n is undefined. I am getting this error in the console